# Python How to plot error in Neural Network

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm learning neural networks from the http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/27/python-network-part2/ blog. I want to plot error as in the picture using matplotlib.

[image]

How can I do that? I try to store data in list, but my solution it's not working.
From the trask blog:

> Let's try to plot what the error plane looks like for the
>   network/dataset above. So, how do we compute the error for a given set
>   of weights? Lines 31,32,and 35 show us that. If we take that logic and
>   plot the overall error (a single scalar representing the network error
>   over the entire dataset) for every possible set of weights (from -10
>   to 10 for x and y), it looks something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

# 2 layer neural network

def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1 / (1+np.exp(-x))
    return output


def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)


X = np.array([
    [0,1],
    [0,1],
    [1,0],
    [1,0]
])

y = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

synapse_0 = 2*np.random.random((2, 1)) - 1

data = list()

for iter in xrange(1000):

    layer_0 = X
    layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, synapse_0))

    layer_1_error = layer_1 - y

    layer_1_delta = layer_1_error * sigmoid_output_to_derivative(layer_1)
    synapse_0_deriative = np.dot(layer_0.T, layer_1_delta)

    synapse_0 -= synapse_0_deriative

    data.append(np.array([layer_0, layer_1, layer_1_error]))

    print "Error: {}".format(layer_1_error)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# x,y,z,c = data

print data


# surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
#                        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

EDIT:

I try with:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1 / (1+np.exp(-x))
    return output


def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)

X = np.array([
    [0,1],
    [0,1],
    [1,0],
    [1,0]
])

y = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

synapse_0 = 2*np.random.random((2, 1)) - 1

layer_1_error = ""

errors_sum = np.array([])

for iter in xrange(12):

    layer_0 = X
    layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, synapse_0))

    layer_1_error = layer_1 - y

    layer_1_delta = layer_1_error * sigmoid_output_to_derivative(layer_1)
    synapse_0_deriative = np.dot(layer_0.T, layer_1_delta)

    synapse_0 -= synapse_0_deriative

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(range(-10, 10), range(-10, 10), layer_1_error,  linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

And result:

[image]

I don't known how to collect all `layer_1_error` in for loop.

Comment: The loop makes no sense. It seems like you would have the same values for every iteration.

Comment: Why? Look at article on blog.

Comment: @RobertoTrani Do you mean `sigmoid(x)` function yes? Can you explain?

Comment: The question was not clear to me initially. I read the blog just now and the plot surface represents the error obtained varying the two weights of the neural network, not the error of the trained model with respect to the target function to learn. Thus I delete my previous comment and I will try to answer your question soon.

Comment: @RobertoTrani ok, thanks. I will wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to plot the error surface with respect to the synapses weights is to vary the weights and evaluate the average error of each combination. Here you can find a sketch of the code to do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))
    return output

def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)

X = np.array([
    [0,1],
    [0,1],
    [1,0],
    [1,0]
])
y = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1]]).T

synapse_0 = np.empty((2,1))

# the error aggregation starts here
x_range = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20, dtype=np.float)
y_range = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20, dtype=np.float)
errors = []
for _x in x_range:
    synapse_0[0] = _x
    for _y in y_range:
        synapse_0[1] = _y

        # apply the model to the input
        layer_0 = X
        layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, synapse_0))

        # evaluate the error using the RMSE
        error = np.mean(np.sqrt((layer_1 - y) ** 2))
        errors.append(error)

# in order to plot we need to transform x,y and z in 2D array 
error_surface = np.reshape(np.array(errors), (x_range.shape[0], y_range.shape[0]))
_X, _Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range, indexing='ij')

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(_X, _Y, error_surface, cmap=cm.YlOrBr_r, edgecolor='gray', linewidth=0.004, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is the following:
[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. How to correct your code for this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjJ3R.gif ?

Comment: Sorry there was a naming conflict and the computer error was wrong. Now it is fixed and tested.

Comment: Ok, thanks, why are you using two for loops? Is it possible to visualize other network elements?

Comment: I used the two loops to iterate over the possible values of the two weights, which are used to set synapse_0 at each iteration. My favourite visualization of the network elements during the training is http://playground.tensorflow.org/